# How do I repeatedly run code in a C# system tray application (Like on a timer)?

Tags: c#, winforms

I started with a default Windows Forms Application in C# and all I changed was Progam.cs. From the main function, I changed

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

to

```
Application.Run(new MyCustomApplicationContext());
```

Which refers to a custom class (MyCustomApplicationContext:ApplicationContext) that runs my program as a system tray icon instead of a Windows Form. The constructor contains this code:

```
private NotifyIcon trayIcon = new NotifyIcon();
trayIcon.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu(
    new MenuItem[] 
    {
        new MenuItem("Exit", Exit)
    });
```

This allows the user to right click the icon, giving them a context menu with an "Exit" option that will run a function that closes out the program.

At the end of the constructor of MyCustomApplicationContext, I call a recursive function in the class called Update() which executes a ping function and changes the system tray icon depending on the ping delay.

Unfortunately I believe because it's recursive, it isn't allowed to run any other code, so the right click context menu doesn't ever show up. I'd rather call the Update() function through an event, like the System.Timers.Timer Elapsed event. I just don't know how events work or where to put the code.

Comment: Because your constructor is calling a recursive function it never completes, and the object is not usable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'r right, recursive call blocks your app main thread what stops any interaction in GUI. If you had application wth form Windows would mark it as "(Not responding)".

You can use Timer class

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx

```
        var timer = new Timer(tick_milliseconds);
        timer.Elapsed += DoOnTimerClick;
        timer.Enabled = true;
```

Comment: Well there you go! I had no idea it was as simple as that. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

As dmay has stated you can use a Timer class to call your update function; however, from reading your description, it sounds like your going to need to take into account threading here as well.

```
...
aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);

// Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer.
aTimer.Elapsed += UpdateTimer;
aTimer.Interval = 2000;
aTimer.Enabled = true;
...

public delegate void delUpdate();  // This is your delegate. Put it in your MyCustomApplicationContext class.

// This method will invoke your delegate method.
public void UpdateTimer(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Invoke((delUpdate)Update);
}
```

The reason for using the Invoke method is that the timer is going to be running from another thread, and if you want to call a method that updates your User Interface, you'll need to [Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) your Control. Otherwise you'll generate an exception by trying to access objects that do not belong to the thread that the timer is firing from.